# Use function after generated by extraction from Coq to Ocaml

Tags: ocaml, coq, coq-extraction

I have a folder `tmp` which is generated after I do extraction from coq to ocaml.

```
~/tmp/cpf0.ml cpf0.mli cpf0.o cpf0.cmi cpf0.cmx cpf0.cmo
```

`main.ml` is a file I use to call one function in `cpf0` :

```
let prf = Cpf0.proof;;
```

I got an error saying `Cpf0.proof` is unbound. 
I tried to used: (`proof` exists in `Cpf0`).

```
open Cpf0;;
let prf = proof;;
```

I got the same error.

Ocaml linking: `ocamlc -I tmp -c main.ml`

I don't understand why it does not accept `Cpf0`?

But `open Cpf0;;` alone, the linking does not give me any error. I tested with another file in `tmp`, it is able to use all functions of that file.

Comment: I am having a lot of trouble understanding your sentences. Please try to fix your message! You're missing verbs and words all around. :(

Comment: i changed "combine" to "linking" in the question - suspect you had used wrong english word? (sorry don't know answer)

Comment: Thank you, the problem was `proof` is a type and not a function.

Answer (score 1):

When such a problem arises, i.e. you have a module `X` defined, but `X.x` is not defined, you should start the toplevel and try `module S = X` to see what is exactly available in `X`.